# GCC 4.2 Template strange error

Tags: c++, xcode, templates, gcc

i have the following code compiled with GCC 4.2 / XCode.

```
template <typename T>
class irrProcessBufferAllocator
{
public:

    T* allocate(size_t cnt)
    {
        return allocProcessBufferOfType<T>(cnt);
    }

    void deallocate(T* ptr)
    {
        if (ptr)
        {
            releaseProcessBuffer(ptr);
        }
    }

    void construct(T* ptr, const T& e)
    {
        new ((void*)ptr) T(e);//"error: expected type-specifier before 'e' " and
//error: expected `;' before 'e'
    }

    void destruct(T* ptr)
    {
        ptr->~T();//error: expected class-name before ';' token
    }

};
```

i really can't figure out how to fix the errors.
please help,

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to make sure, you are not missing necessary includes: `<cstddef>` for `std::size_t` and `<new>` for placement new?

Otherwise those functions would appear to be correct. If that is the entire allocator, it has other flaws, such as missing required typedefs, `address()` and `max_size()` methods, as well as a `rebind` template.

---

Edit: The only cause for the error could be that you have a function-style macro T defined.

```
#define T(z) zzz
```

would make the preprocessor replace all `T()`'s it encounters, but leave the `T`s not followed by brackets.

You could just rename the template argument.

Comment: The stddef is not missing. After including the <new> header the problem still exists.

Comment: @Raxvan (well, rather @ future readers) How can you call _that_ a "fix"? didn't you learn anything here? Now what if tomorrow you have a new macro named -- wait for it... `TYPE`? will you "fix" it again by renaming the template parameter to `OBJECT_TYPE`?... **The point:** _Don't use ALL_CAPS names for anything else than MACROS._ (A "real" fix would have been to rename the template parameter from `T` to e.g. `Tp` or `T_`, _and also_ rename the macro from `T` to something more descriptive and not commonly-used as a template parameter name...)

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
template <class T> 
class irrProcessBufferAllocator 
{ 
public: 

    T* allocate(size_t cnt) 
    { 
        return allocProcessBufferOfType<T>(cnt); 
    } 

    void deallocate(T* ptr) 
    { 
        if (ptr) 
        { 
            releaseProcessBuffer(ptr); 
        } 
    } 

    void construct(T* ptr, const T& e) 
    { 
        new ((void*)ptr) T(e);//"error: expected type-specifier before 'e' " and 


        //error: expected `;' before 'e' 
    } 

    void destruct(T* ptr) 
    { 
        ptr->~T();//error: expected class-name before ';' token 
    } 
};

int main(){
    irrProcessBufferAllocator<int> i, j;
    int *p = new int;
    i.construct(p, 2);
    i.destruct(p);
}
```

Comment: I know this might be the problem , but XCode dosen't tell me the type for witch the template is used. Also this is used alot , and i can't remove this allocator out , i just have to find a fix.

Comment: @GMan: in the OP, the template header(template<class T>....) was not there. that was edited later on :) after I posted.

Comment: vs OP? what do you mean by OP?

Comment: the problem is that xcode doesn't tell me the type T... any way i can find that?

Comment: If you look at the error messages and scroll it carefully, you will see the compiler tells you the type 'T' for which the error is detected.

Comment: Xcode doesn't , i just tell the header in which the problem appeared.

Answer (score 0):

This just points out the problem , doesn't fix it.
i have specialized the template for all POD types by removing the 'new' and '->~T()' from the construct and destruct functions. The errors still appear in the same spot.

Comment: Instead of answering here, please edit your post. The posts here are sorted by up-votes, so you can't actually answer someone's post this way. The other way is to comment on that "someone"'s post (: